# In Android, can we create a bitmap with only one channel?

Tags: android, image

Can we create a bitmap image with only grayscale (8-bit color pixel). There is a ALPHA_8 type for bitmap, can we use it to store a grayscale image?

I am looking into OpenCV as well, and find out OpenCV java library provides the function (Utils.matToBitmap) to convert the Mat to bitmap, however no matter input as rgba or gray image, the output will be in RGB_565 or ARGB_8888, which have 3 or 4 channels.

Will anyone share some ideas on storing a 1-channel grayscale image on Android?

Comment: Use a GIF, instead. These images only have 256 colors.